# Auto generating a pincode depending upon the location selected in HTML form

Tags: php, html

I am currently working on a website that is intended to offer certain services depending upon the location of the user. Now the problem is: How do I auto generate the Pin Code text field depending upon the location selected in the drop down list? My project is based on PHP

http://pastebin.com/5bcbDJ1u - here is the html form

http://pastebin.com/AjzD1GL2 - here is the PHP file used in the action tag of form

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['select'] && $_POST['select'] == 'pincode_123')){ $pin="123"; }` or `$pin = uniqid();` something to that effect. You get the general idea ;-)

Comment: That doesnt work :( how do i get the selected value of the option list using php?

Comment: *"That doesnt work"* - That doesn't tell me much; doesn't work *with what?*

Comment: when I used your code in the HTML form the $_POST was not able to get the value of the location selected.

Comment: You're behind your computer, and I'm behind mine.

Comment: and i'm behind @Fred-ii- with a cheese grater.

Comment: Can you come over teamviewer? or do you want me to add code?

Comment: ok i have edited my main question and added the code in pastebin for some reason stackoverflow wont display my html code as it is interpreting it.

Comment: You're going to need to tell us what it is you want to generate, from what and how. Give us an example output you want and from which form element(s).

Comment: @Dagon Parmesan'ing? Want some "spaghetti code" to go with that?